# How to serialize and deserialize Django ORM query (not queryset)?

Tags: python, sql, django, serialization

My use case is that I need to store queries in DB and retrieve them from time to time and evaluate. Thats needed for mailing-app where every user can subscribe to a web-site content selected by individually customized query.
Most basic solution is to store raw SQL and use it with `RawQuerySet`. But I wonder is there better solutions?

Comment: who writes those queries and how? do you not worry about sql injection issues?

Comment: User passes some content-specific parameters into a form, then view function, that recieves `POST`, constructs query and stores it in DB.

Answer (score 3):

At first glance, it is really dangerous to hand out query building job to others, since they can do anything (even delete all your data in your database or drop entire table etc.)

Even you let them build a specific part of the query, it is still open to [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). If it is ok for all those dangers, then you may try the following.

This is and old script I used and let users set a specific part of the query. Basics are using `string.Template` and `eval` (the evil part)

Define your Model:

```
class SomeModel(Model):
    usr = ForeingKey(User)
    ct = ForeignKey(ContentType) # we will choose related DB table with this
    extra_params = TextField() # store extra filtering criteria in here
```

Lets execute all queries belongs to a user. Say we have a `User` query with `extra_params` `is_staff` and 'username__iontains'

> usr: somebody
>
> ct: User
>
> extra_params: is_staff=$stff_stat, username__icontains='$uname'

`$` defines placeholders in extra_params

```
from string import Template
for _qry in SomeModel.objects.filter(usr='somebody'): # filter somebody's queries
    cts = Template(_qry.extra_params) # take extras with Template
    f_cts = cts.substitute(stff_stat=True, uname='Lennon') # sustitute placeholders with real time filtering values 
    # f_cts is now `is_staff=True, username__icontains='Lennon'`
    qry = Template('_qry.ct.model_class().objects.filter($f_cts)') # Now, use Template again to place our extras into a django `filter` query. We also select related model in here with `_qry.ct.model_class()`
    exec_qry = qry.substitute(f_cts=f_cts)
    # now we have `User.objects.filter(is_staff=True, username__icontains='Lennon')
    query = eval(exec_qry) # lets evaluate it!
```

If you have all relted imports done,then you an use `Q` or any other query building option in your extra_params. Also You can use other methods to form `Create` or `Update` queries.

You can read more about [`Template`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings) form there. But as I said. It is ***REALLY DANGEROUS*** to give a such option to other users.

Also you may need to read about [Django Content Type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)

Update: As @GillBates mentioned, you can use a dictonary structure to create the query. In this case, you will not need `Template` anymore. You can use json for such data transfer (or any other if you wish). Assuming you use json to get the data from an outer source following code is a scratch that uses some variables from the upper code block.

> input_data : '{"is_staff"=true, "username__icontains"="Lennon"}'

```
import json
_data = json.loads(input_data)
result_set = _qry.ct.model_class().objects.filter(**_data)
```

Comment: Why we need to use `eval`, we can just convert `extra_params` to a `dict` and unpack it to `.filter()` like `**kwargs`

Comment: You are right, as I said It was an old code. It was easier to do it with that I guess.

Comment: Why you say that it is dangerous? User just passes some params and backend make queries with them - every web-app do this. I think I will stick with this solution, I will store queries in DB like `param__lt=100, param2__isnull=False`. But is there way to serialize `QuerySet` object (not a form data) to this notation?

Comment: Sql injection is not possible in this solution, but users may reach important data since they can reach every record in the data base (if op allows them) or can change data if OP lets them to update. It was simple and basic Django DB api but still I need to tell that he will give data access to other people because I do not know who will use this. Beside that, it is simple Django DB api.

Answer (score 2):

According to your answer,

> User passes some content-specific parameters into a form, then view function, that recieves POST, constructs query

one option is to store parameters (pickle'd or json'ed, or in a model) and reconstruct query with regular django means. This is somewhat more robust solution, since it can handle some datastructure changes.

Comment: I thought about that solution - and it have one disadvantage - with it  there some 'subscription-category' must be defined in code and it must contain queries-patterns, to which stored parameters will be applied every time.

Comment: did not understand passage about `subscription-category`. Do you use ORM (`filter`, `extra` etc.), or you have own SQL-generator? In any case you have to have those patterns implemented, just move all query-generating logic to one place, and you're done (you can use it both in view and for evaluation). if performance can be an issue, you can also store generated SQL, but I strongly reccomend to store metadata, you'll regret you don't have it when will be changing you underlying tables

Comment: If I store parameters in DB - so I need a code that takes that parameters - that code is what I meant by `subscription-category`

Comment: Another problem with that solution - if scheme of how query constructs change, parameters stored in DB for each user will become invalid, and all subscriptions will be cancelled.

Comment: Sorry? this process IS called database migration. I had a project where somewhat similar task was solved, with constantly changing database design (business requirement). That wasn't sql though, but some evaluated data according to bunch of params that changed monthly. We stored params along with generated data, along with version of generator used, and regenerated every time set of parameters changed. that involved complex migration strategies implementation, but worked well.

Comment: but to make long story short, if you feel that your subscription parameters wont change, and are satisfied with raw sql solution, why do you ask a question? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new model `user_option` and store the selections in this table. 
From your question, it's hard to determine whether it is a better solution, but it would make your user's choices more explicit in your data structure.